# walletconnect throws 'pairing already exist'

Tags: wallets, walletconnect

Im currently newby to walletconnect.

I'm currently facing bunch of errors and couldn't figure out...

any advise or help will really help me a lot

I'm trying to make a connection between my wallet with 'uniswap' via walletconnect(essential)

below is my settings & code

btw , application runs on 'localhost'

```
const signClientOption = {
    projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
    relayUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_RELAY_URL2,
    metadata: {
      name: 'React Wallet',
      description: 'React Wallet for WalletConnect',
      url: 'https://walletconnect.com/',
      icons: ['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37784886']
    }
}

(async function(){
            const signClient = await SignClient.init(signClientOption);
            const c = await signClient.core.pairing.pair({ uri : 'wc:30771a74-d5d9-4667-b5f3-d3d004a9c8b5@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2Fr.bridge.walletconnect.org&key=445cae9ff2c87bed09a58ab4464c35353b1581500f361ffd98461b92ee0e058c'});
// uniswap wc
            console.log(c)
})()
```

then it shows error as below

[image]

and on network tab,, two kind of request r send and it fails with 422 status code (attesation)

[image]
[image]

at last, below is my localstorage stored values, and on session storage, nothing is stored

[image]